# Is there a way to get a "table like" appearance to my dropdown entries?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Using a fixed-width font (e.g. Consolas, Courier, etc), I am trying to 
populate a dropdown menu (AjaxControlToolkit:DropDownList) that has 2 
columns (in appearance). I have a product name and a category name 
(neither of which I know until runtime). The appearance I'm looking 
for is something like:

```
               Chevy Cruz     (gas)
               Prius          (hybrid)
               Tesla Model S  (electic)
```

My list can have over 300 entries and if I just append the category to the 
product name, the menu is harder to read.

I've tried using a character array and copying in the category name at the
same index for each ListItem, but the spaces between disappear when the 
dropdown list is opened. I've looked at the ListItem(Paragraph) constuctor
but it doesn't look to solve my problem to my understanding of it. I
haven't looked at the Telerik controls I have available because it
would mean a lot of coding changes.

I can't think of another AjaxControlToolkit control that might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select Multiple Html with columns - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213160/select-multiple-html-with-columns-possible)

Answer (score 0):

string padding might be works for you

```
var _maxLengthOfProductName = 20; //number of space you need
var _productName = "Product Name";
var _type = "(type)";
var _ProductNameWithType = _productName.PadRight(_maxLengthOfProductName, ' ') + _type; //assign this to the dropdown item
_ProductNameWithType = _ProductNameWithType.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

it will show

```
Product Name        (type)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, I tried this approach but once again, the padding disappears once added to the dropdown control.

Comment: sorry I forgot, just edit my answer.. try '&emsp;' or '&nbsp;'

Comment: '&nbsp;' is not a character literal.

Comment: sorry, just edit to use char and replace it with nbsp;

Comment: The spacing still disappears once added to the dropdown.